# Travel options from Barcelona to Skydive Empuriabrava

Tags: spain, barcelona, parachutes-skydiving

We are travelling to Spain at the end of this month and as a part of the trip, we are planning to do skydiving at this one of the most beautiful skydiving locations in the world, [Skydive Empuriabrava](https://www.skydiveempuriabrava.com/en/).

There are [multiple ways](https://www.skydiveempuriabrava.com/en/how-to-get-there/) to reach at this location using public transit as posted on the link below but not sure about the frequencies and schedule of bus and train and at the same time any idea about which option will be convenient as well as less expensive?

Here are the options I found so far:

1) Train from Barcelona - Figures and then a bus to Empuriabrava

Problem with the option is I can book AVE train tickets online but could not find a way to know bus schedule and ticket booking site.

2) Rental Car

You can rent a car and go to the location, they have free parking available as well but have no idea about the traffic on the road.

Comment: If you take the train to Figueres, you can take a taxi or [the bus](https://bit.ly/2Kt4oWI). The bus, #12, runs [somewhat infrequently at times](http://www.moventis.es/sites/moventis/files/line/files/alt_emporda_hivern_2018-2019_1.pdf), so it's not a great option, but I'm sure the skydiving place is well used to answering questions and can provide specific guidance when you contact them to make your reservation. I'd talk to them for specific information since they have local knowledge.

Comment: @ZachLipton Thanks for the explanation and answer. Do you know is it easy to find a taxi or ride-sharing service? I will call skydiving location to check about that as well

Comment: I really don't, sorry. Surely most of the skydiving company's customers are coming in from Barcelona, so they'd be the best ones to advise you.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, thanks for all the comments and help out there. Here are total possible options based on my research, community member opinions and from the company itself:

**Best Option**

Take a train from Barcelona Sants station to Figures and then Bus #12 will take you the location. There is hardly a 1 min walk at the end.
A bus station and a train station is very close in Figures.

There is enough frequency for both bus and train on weekdays. However please consider that on weekend and weekday evenings this get little trickier and you might not find a bus easily for Figures.

**Alternate Options to/from Figures**

When you have a hard time to find a bus according to your schedule, you can always hire a taxi to the Figures and then take a train to Barcelona.

I checked with Skydiving location and they said taxi service runs 24 * 7.

**Other Options from Barcelona**

**Rental Car:**
You can always rent a car from Barcelona and take a 2 hr drive to this place, I guess this is convenient if you are okay to drive a car in Spain. (Spain has the same side of driving as the US. Please check this for your country as well before taking this option)

If you want to drive a car in Europe then you need to get IDP. IDP along with US driving license is required to drive a car in Spain.

**Bus**

There is also bus service runs from Barcelona to Figures, but I guess this is not a convenient option at all as you will spend a lot of time on the road and will not enjoy your day out totally.

[Way to reach directly from Airport](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Barcelona+El+Prat+Airport,+Barcelona+(Airport+T2C),+Spain/Skydive+Empuriabrava+-+The+Land+of+the+Sky,+Carrer+Aeroclub,+Empuriabrava,+Spain/@41.991145,2.6939745,10.3z/am=t/data=!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x12a49e89a378c245:0x65a3fba48d7574b2!2m2!1d2.07972!2d41.30431!1m5!1m1!1s0x12ba61e85f7be7cf:0xd69d261f86a3a9e1!2m2!1d3.1092656!2d42.2588553!2m3!6e1!7e2!8j1566043200!3e3)

**Summary**

1) Rental car

2) Train to figures and then taxi/bus

are the best possible options to reach Skydive Empuriabrava.

*Enjoy your day when you will not just travel but will fly too!!!*

Comment: You should note that the AVE station in Figueres (Figueres-Vilafant, where the high-speed train from Barcelona will stop) isn't so close to the bus station, it's about a 30 minute walk

Comment: @Greg so the OP needs to take a local service to Figueres station which is near the bus station. It is not that quick but would avoid the walk.